# How to construct a counter-model of □P --> □◊P in T and K?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I am new to modal logics and would really appreciate it if someone would be able to help me out with this practice question. I’ve established the validity theorem in T with an axiomatic proof, but I can’t seem to wrap my head around how to derive the same result by constructing a counter model in T, and to show that it does not hold in weaker system.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy SE. Can I ask if this is a homework question? These are alright provided you show what research you've already done and limit your query to a specific element you're having trouble understanding. As such, you might like to expand your answer with some more detail and make your query more specific to avoid closure.

Answer (score 4):

There is no counter-model in T, since it is a theorem of T.

As for K, take a model with two worlds **α** and **β** where β is possible relative to α, but nothing is possible relative to β. Make P true in β. Then your sentence fails in α.